# C# finding all text between markers and modifying each found instance

Tags: c#, regex, search, replace, markers

I have a string coming from an external source that contains start and end markers (*two asterisks*) around important text. I'm displaying this text in an html file and I need to parse the string first with `C#` and bold any marked text including the markers.

Hopefully the below shows what I'm trying to accomplish...

```cs
    public static void Main()
    {
        string orginalText = "Cat dog ** monkey ** lizard hamster ** fish ** frog";
    
        Console.WriteLine(ReplaceMarkedText(orginalText));
    }

    string ReplaceMarkedText(string text)
    {
        // This is the closest I've gotten so far, but it only works with one pair of asterisks.
        var matches = Regex.Match(text, @"\*\*([^)]*)\*\*").Groups;
        string newText = text.Replace("**", string.Empty);
        foreach (Group match in matches)
        {
           if (match.Value.Length > 0)
           {
                newText = newText.Replace(match.Value, "<b>**" + match.Value + "**</b>");
            }
        }

        return newText;
    }
```

What I want to see in console output: `Cat dog <b>** monkey **</b> lizard hamster <b>** fish **</b> frog`

Comment: For a quick way I would loop through all the occurrences of ** and alternate inserting <b> and </b> before and after

Comment: After splitting on `"**"` into array `a` you could `string.Concat(a.Zip(a.Select((_,i) => i == a.Length - 1 ? "" : (i % 2 == 0 ? "<br>**" : "**</br>"))));`

Comment: Code: `Regex.Replace(text, "\\*{2}.*?\\*{2}", "<b>$&</b>")`.

Comment: @RyszardCzech Thank you! Works great, and simple one line.

Comment: @CaiusJard I wasn't able to get this to work as is. VS says Zip needs a 2nd argument. I couldn't figure it out what it would be. I like your solution as it doesn't rely on regex (although I'm not opposed to it either).

Comment: Oh, Zip with only a single argument needs net core; I guess you're on net framework. You could add `,(a,b)=>a+b` to the Zip call

Comment: All in a looped solution might be most efficient; Make a string builder, do an indexof for **, while the index != -1 insert currentindex to nextondex, followed by a Boolean that flip flops to decide whether to insert br or /br, then repeat the indexof from the index+2

Comment: All in like the regex approach the most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```cs
string Result = Regex.Replace(text, "\\*{2}.*?\\*{2}", "<b>$&</b>");
```

See [regex proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C*%7B2%7D.*%3F%5C*%7B2%7D&i=Cat%20dog%20**%20monkey%20**%20lizard%20hamster%20**%20fish%20**%20frog&r=%3Cb%3E%24%26%3C%2Fb%3E).

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \*{2}                    '*' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \*{2}                    '*' (2 times)
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks for link to regex proof, very helpful!

Comment: Using regex proof and your explanation of `.*?`, I realized a use case that I do need it to span \n and accomplished it with the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option. So... `string Result = Regex.Replace(text, "\\*{2}.*?\\*{2}", "<b>$&</b>", RegexOptions.Singleline);`. Thanks!